# for loops clone output

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop

I'm very new to C#, as you will probably notice from my problem. I've been making a "Røverspråk"-translator to learn some basics. "Røverspråk" is kind of like Pig Latin: The rules are that you exchange every consonant with the consonant + "o" + the consonant. So far so good, and that part works. My problem comes when I'm trying to translate it back.

"totimom" should return "tim", but instead returns this: `"ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiimmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm"`. So it returns every letter 38 times - same amount that i have in my konsonant-string (norwegian konsonants);

string kons = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwz";

Why is it returning every one 38 times? As far as i can tell, the for loops are separated just like in my translator. The code that gives me trouble:

```
 public void OversettTilbake(string vok, string kons)
    {
        string nyText = textBox2.Text.ToString().ToLower();

        for (int e = 0; e < nyText.Length; e++)
        {
            for (int f = 0; f < kons.Length; f++)
            {
                if (nyText[e] == kons[f])
                {
                    newText2.Add(nyText[e].ToString());
                    e = e + 2;
                }

            }
            for (int g = 0; g < kons.Length; g++)
            {
                if (nyText[e] != kons[g])
                {
                    newText2.Add(nyText[e].ToString());
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

The translator that works:

```
 public int Oversetter(string text, string vok, string kons)
    {
        int Count = 0;
        char tom = ' ';

        for (int e = 0; e < text.Length; e++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < kons.Length; i++)
            {
                if (text[e] == kons[i])
                {
                    newText.Add((text[e]).ToString() + "o" + (text[e]).ToString().ToLower());
                    Count = Count + 1;
                }

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < vok.Length; i++)
            {
                if (text[e] == vok[i])
                {

                    newText.Add((text[e]).ToString());
                    Count = Count + 1;
                }
            }
            if (text[e] == tom)
            {
                newText.Add(text[e].ToString() + (text[e].ToString()));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < tegn.Length; i++)
            {
                if (text[e] == tegn[i])
                {
                    newText.Add((text[e]).ToString());
                }
            }

        }

        return Count;
    }
```

EDIT: Thanks for all the fantastic input here. Ive really learned a lot. This solution from @cahinton seems to work perfectly, and wasnt to hard for me to understand and implement:

```
for(var e = 0; e < nyText.Length; e += 1) {
newText2.Add(nyText[e].ToString);
if(kons.Contains(nyText[e])) {
    e += 2;
}
```

}

EDIT2: I do not have the nesessary reputation to upvote here. But thank you all a million times! I expected to get one or two answers within the next week, so gotta say im overwhelmed by the community here. Thanks again!

Comment: Never, *never*, **NEVER** change the loop ariable within the `for` loop! Use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar never? what if i want to skip the next element? I need an additional boolean now you have forbidden me from doing `i++;`.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your quick reply. Could you elaborate on that, though?

Comment: @Gusdor I know that sometimes there are reasons to skip elements, but in that case (even though it's a replacement for a while loop) you shouldn't use `for`, but a real `while` loop. Some languages don't even compile when you change the `for` variable.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar so _"never, never NEVER"_ actually mean't _sometimes, language dependant but probably not in this case_. Top advice... This question is labelled c#, where changing the range variable is legal.

Comment: @Gusdor No. I really mean *never* change the `for` variable within the `for` loop. It will only cause you trouble. No matter which language. A `for` loop is considered a "linear loop" from `a` to `b` (maybe skipping more than one element). Changing the loop index variable within the loop destroys this semantic and leads to confusion if not severe problems. Just because you *can* doesn't mean it's a good idea. Like shooting your own foot, for example. You can, but it hurts ;-)

Comment: Off topic, but you should really try to use english when you name your methods and variables.

Comment: @JohanMagnusson Yes, i can see how that would be a lot better. It will all be in english next time. Thank you.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar my question still stands - how do i skip the next element in your dystopian fantasy world?

Comment: @Gusdor And I answered it before: using a `while` loop. Personally I don't care what you do. It's just good practice *not* to do it and it's just an advice to an obviously novice programmer, which I bet will save is butt sooner or later. I've seen enough code that produced the most absurd results due to exactly that, and personally I think that *all* languages should protect the `for` index variable at compile time already. Still, I'll end this discussion here, as obviously this doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting all the duplicates because of your g loop.  For every consonant that doesn't match, you're adding the character you are looking at to your target string.  The code could be simplified like this:

```
for(var e = 0; e < nyText.Length; e += 1) {
    newText2.Add(nyText[e].ToString());
    if(kons.Contains(nyText[e])) {
        e += 2;
    }
}
```

You can improve the `Contains` lookup performance by changing kons from a `String` to a `HashSet` of chars:

```
HashSet<char> kons = new HashSet<char>() {'B', 'C', 'D', /* etc... */ };
```

Comment: This works absolutely perfectly! And its not to complicated for me to understand. I tried something like this earlier, but hadnt realized the skip 2 yet. Im sorry to say i dont have the reputation to upvote, but you have my full gratitude!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "g" loop: you will get a mismatch for almost every consonant.

Instead modify the "f" loop to set a "found" boolean to "true" (initialize to "false" before the loop). If the consonant wasn't found, it's a vowel (or other character), so you can add that (once!).

**EDIT**

```
int e = 0;
while (e < nyText.Length) // changed 'for' into 'while'
{
    bool found = false;
    for (int f = 0; f < kons.Length; f++)
    {
        if (nyText[e] == kons[f])
        {
            newText2.Add(nyText[e].ToString());
            e = e + 3;
            found = true;
            break; // break out of the 'for' loop: no need to test further after a match
        }
    }

    // no need for an extra 'mismatch-loop'
    if (!found)
    {
       newText2.Add(nyText[e].ToString());
       e = e + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I get the basics of what your saying here, but im not really able to implement it to my code. Could you give me a couple of hints more?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public string OversettTilbake(string kons)
{
   string nyText = textBox2.Text.ToString().ToLower();

   for (int f = 0; f < kons.Length; f++)
     nyText = nyText.Replace((kons[f] + "o" + kons[f]), kons[f].ToString());

   return nyText;
}
```

Comment: +1 Hehe, now *that's* elegant. Despite lots of string-copying :-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar thanks sir. All i thought was, since youre replacing `b` with `bob` on translate, why not replacing `bob` with `b` on detranslate.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This looks incredibly nice. Ive tried about the same thing with replace in List, but it came back with an error because of the array size. Did not know i could replace in a String.

Comment: @user3515529 - you are not replacing *in* a string, you are generating new strings. That's why it says `nyText = nyText.Replace(..)` and that's the reason behind the "string copy" comment of Thorsten (those old strings need to be cleaned up by the system).

Comment: Hmmm... Doesent look like its quite translating right, though.

Comment: This: The prosecutor immediately boxed the double-amputee athlete into a corner in what his defense team described. Is this in RøverspråK: Tothohe  poprorososecocutotoror  imommomedodiatoteloly  boboedod  tothohe  dodouboblole-amompoputotee  atothohloletote  inontoto  a  cocorornoneror  inon  wowhohatot  hohisos  dodefofenonsose  toteamom  dodesoscocroribobedod. It comes back as this translated back: Tothe  prosecutor  immediately  boed  the  double-amputee  athlete  into  a  corner  in  what  his  defense  team  described.

Comment: You could turn `string nyText = ...` into `StringBuilder nyText = new StringBuilder(...);` and then use `nyText.Replace` without the reassignment. That would prevent the string from being copied all the time.

Comment: @user3515529 The problem seems to be that this solution assumes that the same casing applies to every consonant. So `Tothohe` comes out as `Tothe`, as `Tot` is not being replaced correctly - the code tries to replace `ToT`. On the other hand, the text you try to retranslate doesn't match your own specification you gave, as it would have resulted in the string to be `ToThohe`, as you say "turn a consonant into consonant + 'o' + consonant".

Comment: But it does translate to "Tothohe"? Only i have put ToLower on the second consonant in the translator, so it looks better. That might cause some problems with this code. My bad for not telling before.

Comment: @user3515529 That's what I mean :-) Your "language definition" was faulty :-D Given how you told us it was defined `Tothohe` would be wrong and should be `ToThohe`. The code above only works based on this rule. It does not work if the language rule is `consonant => consonant + "o" + lower case consonant` :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following code works and even only requires one loop, as you can search within a string using `IndexOf`. Please also note that as your consonant array is defined containing both upper and lower case letters, there's no reason to convert the input to lower case. Thirdly, instead of using the `TextBox` within your method, you should pass in the string you want to convert as a parameter.

```
static string kons = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwz";

public static string OversettTilbake(string nyText)
{
    int stringIndex = 0;

    string result = String.Empty;
    while (stringIndex < nyText.Length)
    {
        result += nyText[stringIndex];
        if (kons.IndexOf(nyText[stringIndex]) > -1)
        {
            stringIndex += 3;
        }
        else
        {
            stringIndex++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Call this like

```
Console.WriteLine(OversettTilbake("Totimom"));
```

Actually, your code was easy to simplify to only use one loop, as the rule is that one consonant is replaced by 3 letters. So all you need to do is whenever you meet a consonant, add it to the result and skip two letters. That's it.

Please note that calling `ToString` on `TextBox.Text` is unnecessary, as `Text` is already a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input! The reason for ToLower was that the program would crash when i input a capital letter. Dont know why, since theyr represented in the kons array. Thanks again for all the advide. Did not know i could make the strings global like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newText2 = new StringBuilder();
string nyText = "totesostot1";
const string kons = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwz";

// Loop through each leter
for (int e = 0; e < nyText.Length; e++)
{
    // Print the letter
    newText2.Append(nyText[e].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    // If the letter exists in kons, skip the next 2 letters
    if (kons.Any(t => nyText[e] == t))
    { 
         e = e + 2;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(newText2);
```

Will output test1.

Comment: This looks great. Thank you. Its far beyond my skills and knowledge at the moment, though, and im trying to only implement what i can understand.

Comment: @user3515529 Basically the `kons.Any(...)` construct is the same as an `kons.IndexOf(...) > -1`. It searches whether "there is any character `t` in `kons` that is equal to `nyText[e]`".

Comment: Ah! I see. Thanks a lot for the clearing up! Ill try to get a grasp of this before my next translator-project.